# Replace only some instances of a symbol in an expression depending on what it's multiplying it

Tags: replacement, pattern-matching

I have an expression of the type

```
expr = k*a + j*a + a*f + a*g + h
```

And I would like to set `a=0` but ONLY if it's NOT multiplied by `f` or  `g`.
The result I'd want for the example would look like

```
expr = a*f + a*g + h
```

Is there a simple way to accomplish that?
In general `k` and `j` may be unkown expressions, but I do know the form of `f` and `g`.

Comment: Maybe `expr /. Times[a, b__] /; FreeQ[{b}, f | g] -> 0`?

Comment: Perhaps, `expr /. a Except[f | g] :> 0`? But won'r work if there are other factors in each term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
expr /. {p : (f | g)  a ___ :> p, a -> 0}
```

> ```
> a f + a g + h
> ```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work perfectly and is rather short. Just to understand what's going on, what this line does is: for any element "p" of the expression whose form is "f OR g" times "a" times "0 or more other elements" it replaces with itself (keeping it the same); it also sets "a" to zero. This works because /. uses the first rule in the list that is applicable to each element, and so it never tries to do a->0 to the "p" element since the first rule works. Is that correct?

Comment: @Bibliotebarbarian, that's exactly how/why ot works.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to understand Mathematica patterns better

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
expr = k*a + j*a + a*f + a*g + h;
cl = CoefficientList[expr, a]
  (* {h, f + g + j + k} *)

{1, a} . 
  ReplacePart[cl, 
   2 -> (cl[[2]] /. (# -> 0 & /@ 
        Complement[cl[[2]] /. Plus -> List, {f, g}]))] // Expand
```

> a f + a g + h

Answer (score 1):

```
expr = k*a + j*a + a*f + a*g + h;

expr /. _[_, Alternatives @@ Cases[expr, Except[a | f | g], {2}]] :> 0
```

a f + a g + h